# How to call child component method without breaking encapsulation?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have custom date and time picker component based on vendor components.
If simplified it can look so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-time-picker',
  template: `
    <vendor-date-picker [(ngModel)]="date"></vendor-date-picker>
    <vendor-time-picker [(ngModel)]="time"></vendor-time-picker>
  `
})
export class DateTimePickerComponent {
  @Output() timestampChanged = new EventEmitter<number>();

  date: string;
  time: string;

  reset() {
    this.date = "";
    this.time = "";
  }
}
```

I have a parent component that uses DateTimePicker and needs to reset it state sometimes:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-date-time-picker #dateTimePicker (timestampChanged)="updateDateTime($event)"></app-date-time-picker>
  `
})
export class Parent {
  @ViewChild('dateTimePicker') private _dateTimePicker: DateTimePickerComponent;

  someEvent() {
    this._dateTimePicker.reset();
  }
}
```

The reasons (and related code) why I've created such ugly component from vendors ones is beyond the scope of the question. What is important for me is that using ViewChild breaks encapsulation of a child. And I can't protect other child fields using "private" keyword like "date" and "time" since they are used in template. So the question is whether angular possess mechanism to call child method via some stated public interface (like using inputs) or to protected other child components fields to be still available in template but not accessed externally?

Comment: I'd just go with `ViewChild`. I don't know why you think it breaks encapsulation

Comment: ViewChild is pretty much made for your kind of situations. It is ok to use it, the private fields will not suffer, and if you have public fields they are made to be accessed from other classes

Comment: OOP / SOLID background. That's why I think it's not ok at all.

Comment: That's not an explanation. I don't see the breaking either.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think OP means that there can be potential encapsulation breakage that currently isn't prevented by TS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent component doesn't break `DateTimePickerComponent` encapsulation - as long as `reset` method is considered public. A component is just class instance, and parent component can access its public members.

Considering that both parent and child are first-party components, there's usually no practical encapsulation concerns, because a developer is usually aware of expected use for the components, but this may be an issue for bigger team.

To my understanding, the problem here that is that due to how Angular AOT compilation works, it provides type safety in compiled templates but requires all component members that are used in component template to be `public` - while component template and class can be perceived as single entity by a developer, and these members are in fact private.

One option is to use Hungarian notation and prefix all component members that are de facto private with underscore (this provides [certain benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48939997/3731501), despite what [Angular opinionated style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#properties-and-methods) states) - including the ones that are used in component template. The downside is that a template becomes less readable, due to abundance of underscored properties. Another downside is that this way the notation doesn't help to distinguish members that aren't supposed to be used in template (e.g. most injected services).

Another option is to provide components that are expected to have public members with respective public interface:

```
interface IDateTimePickerComponent {
  reset();
}

export class DateTimePickerComponent implements IDateTimePickerComponent {
  @Output() timestampChanged = new EventEmitter<number>();

  date: string;
  time: string;

  reset() {
    this.date = "";
    this.time = "";
  }
}
```

Which is used like:

```
@ViewChild('dateTimePicker') private _dateTimePicker: IDateTimePickerComponent;
```

Of course, there are other [component interaction options](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), but they shouldn't be preferred just because of encapsulation concerns. OOP principles exist to guide and help a developer, not to make jump through hoops.

Comment: You clearly understood what I was caring about. I really don't like the fact that fields can't be public for the template and the same time private for external use. Yes, using interface really can avoid this problem.

Comment: This is a great answer